# I can't launch a .exe from my UWP application

Tags: c#, xamarin, exe

I'm trying to launch an other application that I made from my UWP application.
So I change my Package.appxmanifest by adding references :

```
 xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10"
 xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
```

Add this extension :

```
 <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="Assets\ConsoleApp1.exe" />
```

And add this capability :

```
<rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust" />
```

Finally, i'm using this line in my app :

```
await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
```

When the .exe is notepadd++ for exemple, it works prefectly. But when i'm trying to use an other exe that i made myself, nothing happens.

The **ConsoleApp1.exe** is taking from my release folder.

Thank's for your help.

Comment: yes, thank you, but if i'm asking some help its because I already search and didn't found something conclusive

Comment: Have you tried another exe application made by yourself?  Have you checked the ConsoleApp1.exe is in the Task Manager while the App try to launch it?

Comment: Yes, I tried an other exe and it's the same issue and the exe isn't showed in the Task Manager

Answer (score 0):

Please include your EXE (and any required supporting files) as `Content` to your UWP project.

Make sure you set them up as `Copy to output`. Then you declare the `FullTrustProcess` extension in the appxmanifest to point at your included EXE, and use the `FullTrustProcessLauncher` API to launch it from the UWP.

For more ,check: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher?view=winrt-22000 .

Comment: Thank's for your help. I tried what you said by adding my exe in my Asset's folder but it doesn't change anything. It is set up as Copy to Output too. May I forgot something about that